# Dificuldade com autorização de API FETCH

Tags: javascript, api

Pessoal estou tendo uma pequena dificuldade para realizar uma autorização de API assim eu estou fazendo o codigo

```
fetch('https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/',{

"method":"GET",
"headers": {
    "Authorization: Bearer test_a8c37778328495ac24c5d0d3c3923b"
} 
}
).then()
```

a documentação pede desta forma :

```
curl -X GET https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer test_a8c37778328495ac24c5d0d3c3923b"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está definindo os `headers` incorretamente, os valores são definidos por `chave: valor`, então o correto seria:

```
fetch('https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/',{
  "method":"GET",
  "headers": {
    // Chave : valor
    "Authorization" : "Bearer test_a8c37778328495ac24c5d0d3c3923b"
  } 
})
```

Leia mais sobre o método `fetch` neste [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers)